# Problems with IK Rigging and Ragdolls

Tags: animation, rigging, unity, inverse-kinematics

I'm currently working on a game that uses an AI system that heavily depends on having humanoid rigs (and ragdoll physics), and I have a modeler/animator who made this character for the game that looks great, it's just having some problems due to the way it was rigged.

The animations work great (though I was unable to make the rig humanoid), but the major problems happen when I force the character into a ragdoll when they die, which results in the following:
[image: Character Death Feet Glitch]
We immediately figured out that it was because of the way the animator used IK targets to make the animations (specifically for the legs), and that since there were no actual feet in the rig aside from the IK targets on the legs, the rig would always think the feet are still standing normally.

We thought adding "dummy" feet into the rig that follow the IK targets would fix the issue, but unfortunately the problem has persisted. What I really want is to not only fix the problem with the feet, but also make the rig a humanoid (for my sake), but unfortunately simply trying to use the dummy feet to make the rig a full humanoid didn't work that great, the characters just kind of stutter around and never pose properly. This is probably because the animations are depending on the IK targets to work, which complicates things.

To give you an idea of the rig, here is my attempt at making the rig humanoid:
[image: Character Humanoid Rig]
So far the only solution people have recommended has been to completely re-do the rig and the animations, which my animator really doesn't want to do as it would take a significant amount of time and prevent him from doing anything else for the game for a few days.

For this reason, I am making this post to see if anyone has any other solution that could fix this problem and not add a significant amount to our work load. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to pose mode, choose the menu "pose-animation-bake action", activate "visual keying, clear parents, clear constraints, and click OK: the animation will be baked as it was done without IK.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that apparently broke everything in the animations. The animations depend on the IK targets for any sort of movements, so removing them resulted in a ton of problems

Comment: The process of baking an animation, if done correctly, creates a new animation that will be applied to a new rig: the new rig is equal to the old one except that it has no IK constraints involved. The resulting body movements will be exactly the same.

Comment: You can duplicate the deform bones and set each one to copy the transforms of the corresponding deform bone in the animation rig, then bake the animation as normal. This is pretty easy to automate with Python.